# How to do pivot type calculations in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have Ship fiscal week numbers from 2015 year until 2099( infinite),invoice dates, product and Amount. How can I calculate this in sql ? We can only charge the user when we ship them and on unique invoice only. So how can I add Unique Invoice +Product + Ship Fiscal Week # + Amount.

My data looks like this :

```
Ship fiscal Week | Year | Invoice Date   |Product | Amount
     12          | 2015 | 5/1/2015       | A      |112
     12          | 2015 | 5/1/2015       | A      |112
     1           | 2015 | 5/2/2015       | B      |115
     52          | 2018 | 5/3/2018       | A      |20000
     11          | 2019 | 1/6/2019       | C      |1123333
     23          | 2019 | 7/6/2019       | A      |112888889
```

I will want to pick unique `invoice date + Ship Fiscal week + unique Year + Product + Amount`.

Please help me.

Comment: Please edit your question and tag it with which DBMS you are using

Comment: In order to clarify your question, it would be good if you could edit your question to show the expected results that corresponds to your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `DISTINCT` in order to get unique values.

If you need something else, please be more clear. It is difficult to understand your question.

Try this:

```
SELECT year, ship_fiscal_week, product, SUM(amount) AS total_amount, SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Product)
FROM table
GROUP BY ship_fiscal_week, year, product
ORDER BY product, year, week
```

Comment: Yes I can add distinct on Unique Invoice, But how will I get total amount per product. I am new to SQL any help is appreciated.

Comment: I edited the answer. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Please create the desired output in a spreadsheet to be certain about what you want. Also, i edited the query to make the weekly aggregation. Try once again.

Comment: ok!  so my desired output shall as per the input I had provided above           Ship fiscal Week | Year | Invoice Date   |Product | Amount   
     12                  | 2015 | 5/1/2015       | A             |112             
     12                  | 2015 | 5/1/2015       | A             |112
     1                   | 2015 | 5/2/2015       | B      |115
     52                 | 2018 | 5/3/2018       | A      |20000
     11          | 2019 | 1/6/2019       | C      |1123333
     23          | 2019 | 7/6/2019       | A      |112888889           Therefore, Total of Product A in 2015 =112

Comment: Maybe you could try sum(amount) over(partition by Product)

Comment: Please tell me the complete Code.

Comment: Just tried again, it throws error, something went wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you  looking for aggregation?

```
SELECT ship_fiscal_week, year, invoice_date, product, SUM(amount) total_amount
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ship_fiscal_week, year, invoice_date, product
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am looking for total amount per product with Unique Invoices in fiscal week.

Comment: @SYKK: did you test the query, is it producing the results that you expect?

Comment: Thank you @ GMB, I did try the query, but I need to get total amount per product, only adding values from Uniques invoices and Ship Fiscal week #, year.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to remove the duplicate data first and then wants the sum -

```
SELECT ship_fiscal_week, year, product, SUM(amount) total_amount
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ship_fiscal_week, year, product, amount
      FROM YOUR_TABLE)
GROUP BY ship_fiscal_week, year, product
```

Comment: I tried this query : SELECT  `Ship Fiscal Week Number` as Ship_week, `Ship Fiscal Year Number` as Year, `Invoice Date (YYYYMMDD)` as Unique_Invoice, `Product Line Label` as Product, SUM(`Extended Net Sales PMAR Amount`) as total_amount
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `Ship Fiscal Week Number`, `Ship Fiscal Year Number`, `Invoice Date (YYYYMMDD)`, `Product Line Label`
      FROM `ecomm_cog`)
GROUP BY `Ship Fiscal Week Number`, `Ship Fiscal Year Number`, `Invoice Date (YYYYMMDD)`, `Product Line Label`. No luck !!

Comment: What error you get? If the result is incorrect, Please post the expected result.

Comment: ok! so my desired output shall as per the input I had provided above Ship fiscal Week | Year | Invoice Date |Product | Amount 12 | 2015 | 5/1/2015 | A |112 12 | 2015 | 5/1/2015 | A |112 1 | 2015 | 5/2/2015 | B |115 52 | 2018 | 5/3/2018 | A |20000 11 | 2019 | 1/6/2019 | C |1123333 23 | 2019 | 7/6/2019 | A |112888889 Therefore, Total of Product A in 2015 =112(taking only unique invoice, year, week  per product)

Comment: I just did, it says every derived table shall have its own alias, I gave alias but no luck !!